# Pass output logs from a program into a function and store the return code in a variable at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, embedded-linux

I have a shell script which has a function to Log statements. `SomeProgram` is another program which is run from my shell script and the logs from it are passed into the function `LogToFile`.

```
#!/bin/sh

LogToFile() {
    [[ ! -t 0 ]] && while read line; do echo "$line" >> $MY_LOG_FILE; done
    for arg; do echo "$arg" >> $MY_LOG_FILE; done
}

SomeProgram | LogToFile
```

**Question:**
All is good until here. But I have been trying to get the return code from `SomeProgram` and store it in a variable. How can I do that without loosing the functionality of logs from `SomeProgram` going into my `LogToFile` function. I tried the following options but in vain.

```
RETVAL=SomeProgram | LogToFile
RETVAL=(SomeProgram) | LogToFile
RETVAL=(SomeProgram | LogToFile)
```

Is it possible to pass the output of a program to a function parameter and collect the return value in another variable at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. [PIPESTATUS](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) is the tool to use here.

Following is the way I can use it to get the return code of `SomeProgram` into `RETVAL` for example.

```
SomeProgram | LogToFile
RETVAL=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

Above is the way of getting the output of the program on the left of the pipe. `PIPESTATUS` is an array which contains the return codes of all the programs run adjacent to the pipe commands.

`PIPESTATUS[1]` could give the output of the `LogToFile` for example if `LogToFile` was a program.